# dash script replace array

Tags: shell-script, dash

This script works if I use bash on my Debian 11 (bullseye). But now I need to refactor it to use Debian's `sh` shell(`/bin/dash`).

```
#!/bin/dash

var1=1
var2=2
var3=3

arr=($var1 $var2 $var3)
exist_var="${arr[*]:+ message}"
echo $exist_var
```

Now, I get a message if any variable is set:

```
tuy@debian$ bash sh_array.sh 
message
```

And I get no message if a variable is not set:

```
tuy@debian$ bash sh_array.sh 
$
```

I know dash does not support arrays. If any of the variables is defined, the script must print a message. If no variables are defined, this script must still work, but without printing a message.

Comment: It would make it easier if you explained exactly what you want to do, because even in bash, I don't expect that script does what you think it does.

Comment: If you run the script as `bash sh_array.sh`, the shebang line (`#!/bin/dash`) is ignored and the script will be run by `bash`. To run with `dash`, either make the script executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/sh_array.sh`) and then run directly (`/path/to/sh_array.sh`) or call it with `dash` instead of `bash`: `dash /path/to/sh_array.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether at least one of the `var1`, `var2` or `var3` variables is set (to any value, including the empty string), in dash, bash or any other POSIX shell, you'd do:

```
if [ -n "${var1++}${var2++}${var3++}" ]; then
  echo At least one of those 3 are set
fi
```

Or

```
set=${var1++}${var2++}${var3++}
echo "${#set} out of 3 of those variables are set"
```

Your code, even in bash, doesn't make much sense:

*`"${arr[*]:+ message}"` expands to `" message"` if the concatenation of the elements of the `arr` array with the first character of `$IFS` in between is not the empty string.

Earlier, you define `arr` as split+glob applied to `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3`.

With the default value of `$IFS`, if all those variables are set but contain only space, tab or newline characters, the `arr` array will end up having no element because of the split part. If `var1` was for instance set to `/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*`, because of the glob part, the `arr` array would end up containing millions of elements if it doesn't crash your machine.